# How to use 2 different constructors with open-zeppelin

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts

I don't understand well how to implement an smart contract to create a capped Token.

If I want to follow the example of a simple token is easy: 
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/examples/SimpleToken.sol

It's use ERC20Detailed, which inhertis from IERC20 (as you see in the docs):
https://docs.openzeppelin.org/docs/token_erc20_erc20detailed

So, you only use the constructor for ERC20Detailed.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

import "../token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "../token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

/**
 * @title SimpleToken
 * @dev Very simple ERC20 Token example, where all tokens are pre-assigned to the creator.
 * Note they can later distribute these tokens as they wish using `transfer` and other
 * `ERC20` functions.
 */
contract SimpleToken is ERC20, ERC20Detailed {
    uint8 public constant DECIMALS = 18;
    uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000 * (10 ** uint256(DECIMALS));

    /**
     * @dev Constructor that gives msg.sender all of existing tokens.
     */
    constructor () public ERC20Detailed("SimpleToken", "SIM", DECIMALS) {
        _mint(msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
    }
}
```

Ok, but what if I also want to implement ERC20Capped? I see that inherits from ERC20Mintable, which inherits from ERC20. But the constructor method of ERC20Capped doesn't include neither token name, nor symbol nor supply.

I have been also checking the source code of these smart contracts, but don't see very clear.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v2.1.2/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v2.1.2/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Capped.sol

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`ERC20Capped` inherits from `ERC20Mintable`, which inherits from `ERC20`.

So if you inherit from `ERC20Capped`, then you don't need to inherit from `ERC20`.

Therefore (though without verifying it via compilation), I'm pretty sure that you can do:

```
contract SimpleToken is ERC20Detailed, ERC20Capped {
    uint8 public constant DECIMALS = 18;

    constructor (uint256 cap)
        ERC20Detailed("SimpleToken", "SIM", DECIMALS)
        ERC20Capped(cap)
        public {
           ...
    }
}
```